# AngularJS - call two functions non sequentially with ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a **Modify** Button, when I want to click on it, the **modify()** function will be executed, and the text button will change to **save**, and I click on it, the **save()** function will be executed.

these are the codes

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="modify(); save()" ng-disabled="!modifyDisabled">{{button}}</button>

$scope.button="Modifier"
$scope.modify=function(){
  $scope.button="Enregistrer"
  $http.get("http://localhost:5000/settings").then(function(response){
    $scope.settingsInserted = false 
    $scope.nbOperateurPresents= response.data.data[0].nbOperateurPresents
    $scope.targetAmount1stHour= response.data.data[0].targetAmount1stHour
    $scope.targetAmount2ndHour= response.data.data[0].targetAmount2ndHour
    $scope.targetAmount3rdHour= response.data.data[0].targetAmount3rdHour
    $scope.targetAmount4thHour= response.data.data[0].targetAmount4thHour
    $scope.targetAmount5thHour= response.data.data[0].targetAmount5thHour
    $scope.targetAmount6thHour= response.data.data[0].targetAmount6thHour
    $scope.targetAmount7thHour= response.data.data[0].targetAmount7thHour
    $scope.targetAmount8thHour= response.data.data[0].targetAmount8thHour
   })  
}

$scope.save=function(){
 console.log('saved')
 $scope.button="Modifier"
}
```

I want to execute for the first click **modifiy()**, and in the second click **save()**.

I think that I should use a third function, but I don't know how !

Who can help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, you need a third function in your controller, which toggles between modify and save. Should be pretty easy:

```
$scope.alreadyModified = false;

$scope.modifyFirstAndThenSave = function() {
  if (!$scope.alreadyModified) {
    $scope.alreadyModified = true;
    $scope.modify();
  } else {
    $scope.alreadyModified = false; // just in case a third click should modify again
    $scope.save();
  }
};
```

Comment: but i have a question, can you explain the concept of what you did ?

Comment: I am storing the previous state in a variable. So I am able to respect this value, when I determine which action to call (modify/save).

In this example I've changed the variable from true to false and the otherway around. You can also achieve this with a single line of code: `$scope.alreadyModified = !$scope.alreadyModified` Because we have a boolean (true/false) here, we can just negate (with leading `!`) the previous value.